ASP.NET Core 8 : migrate EF identity to 3rd party
I have a pretty standard ASP.NET Core 8 app that uses ASP.NET Core identity and EF storage. So users authenticate in the app using local password. I want to switch built-in authentication to something else, for example Azure Entra ID.
I know how to build OAuth2/OpenID authentication without local accounts from scratch. However the problem is that I can't simply drop identity tables from EF, because there are a lot of foreign keys to this table and existing users have associated data.
So the question is: what is my approach to delegate authentication to 3rd party provider (Azure Entra, but it shouldn't matter) and associate external identity with local account. My main aim is to drop local passwords. That is, user authenticates against 3rd party identity provider, receives identity token and provides it to my web app. Then web app somehow associate this token with local user and then grant required access according to internal rules.
PS: I'm not asking for code help, it is more auth migration design question. I'm on ASP.NET Core 8, if it matters.

You can try to log in directly using Azure login, and then use email to check whether the user already exists in the local database and whether it is associated. If it exists and is associated, log in directly. If it is not associated, you can use UserManager.AddLoginAsync or similar methods to save the login information to the AspNetUserLogins table for association. If it does not exist and is not associated, create a new user and then associate the external login. Then you can disable the password management login part in the application.

@YuningDuan do I understand it correctly, that I first configure my app with Azure auth, then after redirection back to my app, I read identity token and then use UserManager to bind (or create if doesn't exist) it to a login in AspNetUserLogins table?

Yes, your understanding is correct. Associate it via email, and then disable the password management login part in the application, and use Azure login directly when logging in.
